# MongoDB: Querying on a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding, querying

I have a sharded cluster named test2.

db.collection.getShardDistribution() gives me this:
[image]

Why does my `.count()` query only return total docs in shard0000 and my iterable only iterates through the documents in shard0000? What do I have to do to make my query return the entire collection?

```
    System.out.println("Total docs: "+db.getCollection(collectionName).count());
    FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection(collectionName).find();
```

Any query I perform with different parameters only iterates through shard0000.

**Edit** Connection string:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("129.241.xxx.xx",27017);
```

This is the error. Should be port 27023. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your connection string? Does it point to the mongos instance? And your collection and your cluster has the same name?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: You query a sharded cluster via the `mongos` instance, so you need to connect to it. Most likely, you are connecting to shard0000 directly. Simply make sure that you connect to your mongos instance. Simply add the connection string and the IP addresses to your question by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34018856/edit)

Comment: No, you need to connect via URI to all your mongos. Take a look [http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClientURI.html)

Comment: @Valijon You don't necessarily *have* to. You can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was connecting to the wrong port after the database was sharded. I had to modify my connection string to use the correct port where my mongo instance was running.

This was my connection string.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("129.241.xxx.xx",27017);
```

Changed the port to

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("129.241.xxx.xx",27023);
```

...and it worked. Thanks to @Markus W Mahlberg for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: On a side note, it is best practice to run `mongos` on port 27017 as it prevents inadvertent connections to shards.